# How to check the input field that does not starts with '-','+','_' using yup

Tags: javascript, regex, next.js, yup

I need to check whether the input given by the user and restrict if the field value starts with '-','+','_' using YUP validation

Thanks in advance

```js
name: Yup.string()
    .required()
    .min(5, 'Too short')
    .matches(/^[aA-zZ\s]+$/, "Only alphabets are allowed for this field ")
    .matches()//code for checking wheather it starts with '+','-','_' if it starts I need to show an error
```

If you could jus share the regex for the following condition

1. Minimum length 5
2. No special characters
3. Cannot start with '-', '_', '+'

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: “*If you could jus share the regex for the following condition*” What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck in that attempt? See [ask]

Comment: Yo I don't know the regex code for the following conditions that I listed above. If you could say the regex code for those situations then I could use Yup to validate the data.

Comment: Why do you need the third condition? Why aren’t the tokens in your third condition “special characters”?

Answer (score 1):

The regex `/^[_\-\+]{1}.*/` should match your desired inputs:

```js
const startsWithSpecialChars = /^[_\-\+]{1}.*/;

console.log('"hello" ==> ', !!'hello'.match(startsWithSpecialChars));
console.log('"hel+lo" ==> ', !!'hel+lo'.match(startsWithSpecialChars));
console.log('"_hello" ==> ', !!'_hello'.match(startsWithSpecialChars));
console.log('"-hello" ==> ', !!'-hello'.match(startsWithSpecialChars));
console.log('"+hello" ==> ', !!'+hello'.match(startsWithSpecialChars));
```

The breakdown:

- `^` indicates the start of the string
- `[_\-\+]{1}` indicates exactly one character of `_`, `-`, or `+` (note the hyphen and plus are escaped)
- `.*` indicates any number of any other character following the underscore, hyphen, or plus

As you can see, `"hello"` and `"hel+lo"` are not matched but `"_hello"`, `"-hello"`, and `"+hello"` are.

Also, for what it is worth, I'm not sure the second condition (`.matches(/^[aA-zZ\s]+$/, "Only alphabets are allowed for this field ")` does what you think it does and/or what it purports to do; you might consider revisiting that.